# Splash and downloading data

Tags: android, download

I have a splash activity, and this activity downloads some XMLs from the internet. All is fine, but the problem is that when the connection is too slow, the OS thinks that the app is unresponsive, and ask to terminate or wait.

How can I prevent this? Or there is a better practice for this kind of things?

Comment: Before implementing Splash screen, check this: [Splash screens are evil, don’t use them!](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=632)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your Download process in a thread or AsyncTask and leave the main UI thread free then OS will not give you the ANR(Application Not Responding) Dialog Box

Tutorial link for AsyncTask

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Answer (score 2):

You're probably downloading the XMLs in the UI thread. Don't. [Use AsyncTasks instead](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).